# Can I play Animal Jam - Play Wild! on Steam without downloading?

Tags: steam, pc, animal-jam-play-wild

I am wanting to play *Animal Jam - Play Wild!* on my PC. Is it possible to play without downloading?

Comment: For the question answerers, it appears that this game is on Steam and is playable on PC: https://store.steampowered.com/app/822240/Animal_Jam__Play_Wild/

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot play *Animal Jam - Play Wild!* on Steam without downloading it first.

I just tried it myself, to make sure, and selecting 'Play Game' on the game's Steam page takes you to a download manager popup for installing the game.

Answer (score 1):

**Animal Jam-Play Wild**

- The Games is now available on steam to play for PC, you can get the game on steam from the following link:https://store.steampowered.com/app/822240/Animal_Jam__Play_Wild/
- If you don't wish to download it you can play the web based game from the following site:https://playwild.animaljam.com

Comment: I can't seem to play the web-based game at https://playwild.animaljam.com on my browser. I tried in both Chrome and Firefox. It appears that there is no browser-based version of this game. What browser did you try this on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to download it, but I'm sorry to tell you that you can't play it.
I tried on Steam, the game doesn't even work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be in line with the other answers.